# Program runs then says it stops working

Tags: c

The program is required to calculate total cost of items and display back to user the quantity of product, product and the price of products as a bill. Keep in mind I am only a beginner in programming in C so basic functions are used.

```
 #include<stdio.h>
 #include<string.h>
typedef struct
{
    float price;
    int quantity;
    char product;
}Billing;
typedef struct
{
    int code;
    char product;
    float price;
}Stocks;
main()
{
    Stocks A;
    Billing B;
    FILE*s;
    FILE*c;
    printf(" Welcome to I.A.M Cash & Carry\n#8 New Trincity Industrial Estate\nTrincity\n");
    printf("=================================\n");
    void transfer(Billing,Stocks,FILE*,FILE*);
    transfer(B,A,s,c);
}
void transfer(Billing B,Stocks A,FILE*s,FILE*c)
{
    int count; 
    s=fopen("C:\\stock.txt","r"); 
    int counter=0;
    while(fgetc(s)!=EOF)
    {
        counter++;
    }
    fclose(s); 
    count=counter;
    Stocks D[count];
    int x; 
    s=fopen("C:\\stock.txt","r");
    for(x=0;x<count;x++)
    {
        fscanf(s,"%d",&D[x].code);
        fscanf(s,"%s",D[x].product);
        fscanf(s,"%f",&D[x].price);
    }
    fclose(s);
    void menu(Billing,Stocks[],FILE*,FILE*,int);
    menu(B,D,s,c,count);
}
void menu(Billing B,Stocks D[],FILE*s,FILE*c,int count)
{
    printf("1)Enter items for billing\n");
    printf("2)Quit\n"); 
    void choice(Billing,Stocks[],FILE*,FILE*,int);
    choice(B,D,s,c,count);
}
void choice(Billing B,Stocks D[],FILE*s,FILE*c,int count)
{
    int x;
    printf("Enter choice:\n");
    scanf("%d",&x);
    if((x<1) || (x>2))
    {
        printf("Choice invalid\nPlease Re-enter\n");
        menu(B,D,s,c,count);
    }
    if(x==1)
    {
        void submenu(Billing,Stocks[],FILE*,FILE*,int);
        submenu(B,D,s,c,count);
    }
    if(x==2)
    {
        printf("Thank you, Have a great day\n");
    }
}
void submenu(Billing B,Stocks D[],FILE*s,FILE*c,int count)
{
    int x,z,quan,prod;
    float sum=0;
    float prices=D[x].price*quan;
    c=fopen("C:\\bill.txt","w");
    do{
    printf("Select choice:\n");
    printf("1)Enter items\n");
    printf("2)Quit");
    scanf("%d",&x);
    if(x==1)
    {
        printf("Enter product code:");
        scanf("%d",&prod);
        for(z=0;z<count;z++)
        {
          if(prod==D[x].code)
          {
            printf("Enter quantity:");
            scanf("%d",&quan);
            fprintf(c,"%d  ",quan);
            fprintf(c,"%s  ",prod);
            fprintf(c,"%5.2f\n",D[x].price*quan);
            sum= sum + prices;
          }
        }
    }
    if(x==2)
    {
        printf("Thank you, Have a great day\n");
    }
}while(x!=2);
fclose(c);
void countbill(Billing,FILE*,float);
countbill(B,c,sum);
}
void countbill(Billing B,FILE*c,float sum)
{
    int y;
    c=fopen("C:\\bill.txt","r"); 
    int x=0;
    while(fgetc(c)!=EOF)
    {
        x++;
    }
    fclose(c); 
    y=x;
    Billing V[y];
    void displaybill(Billing[],FILE*,float,int);
    displaybill(V,c,sum,y);
}
void displaybill(Billing V[],FILE*c,float sum,int y)
{
    int x;
    c=fopen("C:\\bill.txt","r");
    for(x=0;x<y;x++)
    {
        fscanf(c,"%d",&V[x].quantity);
        fscanf(c,"%s",V[x].product);
        fscanf(c,"%f",&V[x].price);
        printf("%d  %s  %f\n",V[x].quantity,V[x].product,V[x].price);
    }
    printf("Total=%f",sum);
}
```

**Debugger output**

[image: Debugger output]

Comment: Have you debugged it? What errors are you getting?

Comment: Learn to use a debugger. It will pay off in the future.

Comment: @Carcigenicate If i click debug, my compiler crashes.

Comment: Drop `void` off when you call the functions from within another function. And you've declared two structs but in code never allocated them.

Comment: @iGunta 1. You don't require a debugger to debug; it's just helpful. 2. I'd work on fixing that if I were you, as debuggers add the exceedingly useful

Comment: Enable all compiler warnings. The `struct` members `char product;` are supposed to be character arrays, not `char`.

Comment: What warnings did your compiler issue about this code?

Comment: @Carcigenicate i inserted a screenshot of what i get when i debug

Comment: Why would you debug a C program at the machine code level???

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please read the [About] and [Ask] pages soon, but even more importantly,
please read about how to create an MCVE ([MCVE]).  Note, in particular, that an MCVE requires information about the input data, and the actual and desired outputs.

Answer (score 0):

im sorry im making this as an answer, i just want you to really read it.
this code have tons of problems, ill just clarify most of them:

1) you are not declaring any of your functions

2) the way you call most of your functions is wrong

3) you are using tons of variable without initializing them, like `x`

4)you cant put a non constant variable in array declaration, it must be a constant number, or use dynamic allocation. (for example `Stocks D[count]`)

and this is only what i saw from general look.

its look like you have some homework to do before you continue this code.

hope its helping somehow.